# Which individual has the highest kill count of any Star Trek crew?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Re-watching Worf shoot another Klingon at point blank range (season 1 episode 20), I wondered if, despite his being Klingon and therefore the token warrior on the series, he actually had the most kills or not of the TNG crew (I almost suspect Riker having more).

Who had the highest *personal* (ie, not destroying a ship) kill count in each series?

Comment: This would be difficult to determine since it is not always established if someone's phaser is set to stun or kill.

Comment: Two questions. One, since you ruled out destroying ships, does taking action or refusing to take action that directly (and willfully) results in death count? Two, does the death have to be on screen or can it be mentioned to have occurred in the character's past?

Comment: @BrianOrtiz Good point

Comment: @Josh I was only considering direct, on-screen kills, but if the mention of a past incident was given in an official capacity (such as a magistrate reading past kills), then that should also be accepted.  Not taking action is only acceptable when it is clear that the character in question _wants_ the other party to die (like when Batman refused to help Ra's al Ghul in the Great Gotham Train Kerplosion)

Comment: If the tortured voices in Q's "Heaven" were a true indicator of Picard's "guilt," then it seems to be Jean-Luc. At least he'd be in the running.

Comment: @n_b having to kill and 'wanting' to are completely different,no-one on the crew wants to kill (except maybe worf), your comment suggest who wants to kill while your post suggest who actually killed.

Comment: @Matt I just wanted to differentiate in cases of non-action due to prime directive vs non-action due to the character perceiving some kind of threat that would be solved by the other party's death.

Comment: Worth considering DS9 in this - given the Dominion War and all that - and assuming any part of Q's game in "All Good Things" was at any time 'real' - then Picard is personally responsible for the destruction of the whole of humankind across time ;)

Comment: So people who die whenever Troi crashes a saucer don't count?

Comment: Worf kills quite a lot of Jem'Hadar in DS9’s [By Inferno’s Light](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/By_Inferno's_Light_(episode)).

Comment: Janeway directly or indirectly killed *a lot* of Borg. Her largest kill counts are almost certainly when she interacts with the Borg Queen directly. Janeway tries to aid the drones that are part of Unimatrix Zero, which leads the Queen to destroying entire ships simply because she can't "hear" a drone or two on those ships any longer, leading to 75,000 drone deaths. And when Admiral Janeway allows herself to be assimilated in the series finale, she kills the Queen which leads to the destruction of the Unicomplex, which assumedly destroyed a lot of drones. I think it's Janeway.

Comment: Would Dr. Stubbs count for using a hand phaser to destroy the nanites in "Evolution" (*TNG*, season 3 episode 1)?  Their "ship" (the computer core) wasn't the target; he was careful to preserve that.  We don't know how many nanites he destroyed, or whether each nanite was a distinct person.

Comment: @Gaultheria - IIRC, the nanites were deemed in the end to be a sentient species?

Comment: Who gets credit for the single death in "In the Pale Moonlight" (DS9 6x19)?  Or does that even count because a ship was incidentally destroyed at the same time?

Comment: @NKCampbell Star Fleet, because they are supposed to be a pretty peaceful people that get into lots of conflicts.  If we were going any character, then the Q continuum has hinted at destroying entire races. Kevin Uxbridge, the Douwd, also vanished a race, the Borg have assimilated an incomprehensible number of races and people, and of course and alternate future Picard kinda destroys the universe.   That’s why it’s specific to Star Fleet and intentional kills, otherwise the numbers get too large.

Comment: @n_b - I actually deleted my comment once I re-read the question closer. It clearly states: "of the TNG crew" - but yeah, I forgot about Kevin. I was thinking Nero because of the word 'crew' in the question ;)

Comment: I say Captain Janeway because her decisions ended up killing a lot of Borg in the Delta quadrant and she also helped the Borg to defeat Species 8472. A lot of Species 8472 died before they went back to their Aquatic Space.

Answer (score -4):

Dr. Phlox of "Enterprise" let all the Valakians die on an entire planet by withholding the cure to the plague affecting them.  The episode's title was "Dear Doctor".

Captain Janeway of "Voyager" gives the Borg the means of committing genocide on Species 8472.

I'd say it was a toss up between those two,

Comment: Actually Janeway would have the highest kill count. She killed the Borg queen and thus countless drones connected to Unimatrix 0, if not almost the entire Collective (minus the liberated drones under Hugh) until they replaced her.

Comment: The question is quite clearly about *personal* kill, i.e. the difference between scheming or being responsible for a person's death in an ethical or judicial sense and pulling the trigger yourself. Thus, I reckon this answer does not really answer the question as stated.